# "Error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’"

Tags: c

I keep receiving this error when I try to compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int    userInt;
    int    x;
    double userDouble;
    char   userChar;
    char   userString[20];

    printf("%d", "%lf", "%c", "%s", userInt, userDouble, userChar, userString);
}
```

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: `"%d", "%lf", "%c", "%s",` -> `"%d %lf %c %s",`, `printf` only cares about the format specifiers from it's first arg.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `"%d"` in the *first* parameter of `print()`, so it (and the compiler, since you are clearly using one that validates printf-style parameters at compile-time) will interpret the *second* parameter as an integer, but you are passing `"%lf"` in the *second* parameter.  A string literal is a `char[]` in C and a `const char[]` in C++, and will decay to a `char*` and `const char*`, respectively.  Hence the error.

You need to put ALL of your format specifiers in the *first* parameter only, eg:

```
printf("%d %lf %c %s", userInt, userDouble, userChar, userString);
```

Or, if you really wanted to separate the values with quotes and commas in the output:

```
printf("\"%d\", \"%lf\", \"%c\", \"%s\"", userInt, userDouble, userChar, userString);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly; I really appreciate it.